# Fatal Execution Engine Error (79FFEE24) (80131506)

Tags: c#, com, clr

I'm encountering problems with my .NET Framework 3.0 SP1 application. It is a C# winforms application communicating with a COM exe. Randomly either the winforms app or the COM exe crashes without any error message and the event log contains this entry:

[1958] .NET Runtime
   Type:     ERROR 
   Computer: CWP-OSL029-01
   Time:     11/25/2008 3:14:10 PM   ID:       1023 
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.1433 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (79FFEE24) (80131506)

I could not find any useful information on the MS sites. Does anybody have an idea where I should start my investigation?

tia

Comment: Okay, we've had enough "MEE TOOOO" answers to this question.

Comment: I encountered this error 80131506 (cor_e_executionengine), while using OllyDbg on my debug .NET executable. Just mentioned for info :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error, it (luckily) went away by installing 3.5 SP1, which bumps your runtime to version 2.0.50727.3053 ([this](http://blogs.msdn.com/dougste/archive/2007/09/06/version-history-of-the-clr-2-0.aspx) is a nice version summary).

While hunting for solutions I found a wild range of suspects for this error. Some people even claimed it was the antivirus (!)

YMMV, good luck.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft released a hotfix

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=16827&wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: this hotfix worked for me, in my case VS crashed when i opened any project under mercurial scc, possible source was the HgSccPackage

Comment: That hotfix doesn't seem to be available any more.

Answer (score 3):

It can be a whole lot of things. Some people repair .NET Framework 3.5, others reinstall .NET alltogether. Some say it's something with PowerCommands, etc. etc. If all else has failed, try what worked for me: 
- start VS up in safe mode
- create a new Windows Forms application
- open your toolbox and delete any special tabs (for me, it was a SQLite tab)
- close and restart in normal mode

If this doesn't work, good luck!

Comment: This actually worked for me.  none of the updates that are linked here worked though except for this.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue on vs 2008 sp1 with asp.net mvc rc1 where opening aspx pages crashed visual studio.

The work around for me is to re-open the solution/project after crash, set project | show all files, and delete the mvc refs for system.web.mvc, system.web.abstractions, and system.web.routing. Then I am able to open the files.

The problem returns later, but I am able to follow the above and I am able to open aspx files afterwards.

Thanks

Eric

Answer (score 0):

These seem to be mainly caused by a bad install of the framework. See if you can repro the error on another machine, or uninstall/reinstall the Framework bits.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior when created GCHandle from IntPtr which was pointing not to a managed object.

Answer (score 0):

The hotfix above worked for me!

The described problem occured when opening any *.aspx page in VS in my ASP.NET MVC (RC1) project.