# Visual Studio closes all the time

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crash

My Visual Studio shuts down about once a day.  Not gracefully either, it just disappears off the screen, process list, everything.  No thinking, no warning, just poof its gone.

This happens most frequently when coderush is trying to do something and lately (the last few days) it happens any time I try to open a view.  As of a few hours ago it is also happening every time I open Globals.asx.cs in an MVC project.

So this is not exactly a programming question but this has been happening for a while and now with ASP.NET MVC out for real it is happening more and more often.

I get the following error in my event log:
.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3082 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A035FC0) (80131506)

I also have the following VS2008 plugins

- Coderush/Refactor Pro! from DevExpress
- ASP MVC
- Testdriven.NET
- T4 Toolbox
- ASP.NET MVC
- MbUnit/Gallio
- Source Outliner
- AnkhSVN (installed very recently)
- Oracle Developer Tools

Has anyone had this problem or can even direct me to where to seek a solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two possibilities here:

1. [Hotfix for Crash related to MVC and plugins](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/03/03/hotfix-available-for-asp-net-mvc-crashes-with-azure-power-commands-resharper.aspx)
2. Reinstall SP1 (I had a coworker who had crashes all the time reapply the SP and it fixed his issue; In his case he had installed VS Database Edition after installing SP1).

Comment: Which part worked, the hotfix or reinstalling SP1? Might be nice if someone else searches and finds this solution to know the minimum they need to do to fix it...

Comment: The hotfix fixed it for me - didn't need to reinstall sp1

Answer (score 3):

You might need to slowly peel back your extensions. The ones that I suspect are:

1. Source Outliner
2. AnkhSVN
3. Oracle Developer Tools

For no other reason than it sounds like an unmanaged extension that would be trampling the process like that.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I have nothing but the standard troubleshooting tips for VS for you:

- Check that you have SP1 installed (and any further updates)
- Delete (rename) all temporary files in your solution such as .suo, .ncb, ...
- Disable all add-ins one by one until the error is gone. Since you have AnkhSVN installed only lately this might be a good first guess...

Also helpful for an analysis are the tools from the [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/0e18b180-9b7a-4c49-8120-c47c5a693683.aspx), mostly I would recommend you [DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) and [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).

There is another similar thread you should check out: [Fatal Execution Engine Error (79FFEE24) (80131506)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334706/fatal-execution-engine-error-79ffee24-80131506)

They also mention a hotfix released by Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=16827&wa=wsignin1.0

As Chris posted this hotfix is [mentioned](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/03/03/hotfix-available-for-asp-net-mvc-crashes-with-azure-power-commands-resharper.aspx) to fix a problem with ASP.NET MVC and Resharper.

Comment: Nah, the problem has been happening for much longer than I've had Ankh but thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2):

A crazy idea that might work:

Open 2 instances of Visual Studio. On one instance you work on your code. On the other you can open some random solution, set it to Debug, then use Attach to Process to attach the first Visual Studio instance to that.

Hopefully when an exception occurs on the first instance which *may* cause it to crash, the second instance will provide a clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work - I think that because it's a Fatal Execution error rather than an exception the debugger doesn't get a change to inspect the process.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to uninstall VMware 6.5 because it was causing the issue. weird.

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/170431

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by uninstalling the WSCF.blue add on.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the silverlight debugging assembly and I stopped getting the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was Gallio 3.0.6.763. After uninstalling, I'm able to load projects in VS2008 again.

Answer (score 0):

I had ASP.Net MVC and Gallio 3.0.6.763. I removed Gallio, and now Visual Studio works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Removing Gallio was also the solution for me. It seems to be some type of conflict between Gallio and ASP.NET MVC projects. I would only get the problem when trying to open an MVC project, specifically a view.

Comment: You should try the hotfix since the issue affects more than just Gallio.

Comment: Since I never used Gallio this was a good solution for me. But I might be installing it again soon with the most recent release and I will definitely try the hotfix if I get the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

The Ankh add-in was causing my Visual Studio to crash silently during compilation. No error message, the entire IDE just disappears from the screen.

By going through each of my add-ins and enabling / disabling and re-trying the compilation, I discovered that it was Ankh that was causing the problem. Completely disabling Ankh is an effective workaround, and you can still manually update and commit with TortoiseSVN.

I haven't as yet figured out the cause of the problem, but I believe it's related to file locking in the cache. Restarting ISS and clearing out the cache (I'm using VS2003) before restarting the IDE tends of fix the problem about 50% of the time. If you absolutely must be Ankh, the following batch script might be useful:

```
iisreset.exe
del /f /s /q "C:\Documents and Settings\(user)\VSWebCache\*"
rmdir /s /q "C:\Documents and Settings\(user)\VSWebCache"
del /f /s /q "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\(version)\Temporary ASP.NET Files\*"
rmdir /s /q "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\(version)\Temporary ASP.NET Files"
```

Just replace "(version)" with your framework version and "(user)" with your user folder.
The script is obviously for Windows XP, so you'll need to modify it if you're using Vista or later.