# .NET 4 exe crashes with 80131506 exit code

Tags: c#, exception, .net-4.0, crash, exe

I'm running the same exact console application on 5 different machines for the last 6 months (almost 24/7) and nothing ever went wrong. Recently I bought 2 new machines and run the application one of the machines works great but the other always crashes after a while and in the Windows Event Log I see the following message:

> The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 000007FEF0469450 (000007FEF0280000) with exit code 80131506" no error stack or anything else

p.s. In this application I work with GCServer = true

Comment: It is hard to diagnose without codes. Try to compare .NET version (major, minor & build number)

Comment: both computers (the new ones) run the same .NET 4.0.30319 (Client Profile & Extended) I also compared the updates same exact updates (other then a few Windows Security Updates)

Comment: as Mark says, when in doubt, run [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Or DebugDiag or smth. similar.

Comment: As you can see here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/334706/fatal-execution-engine-error-79ffee24-80131506, its happened before

Comment: and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478930/suddenly-application-crash-fatal-execution-engine-error-7a0bc59e-80131506

Comment: Jodrell, I already looked into other posts none of them helped. Most talk about .Net update for 2.0 or 3.5. which I assume 4.0 has already

Comment: @Giedrius, what is smth?

Comment: You may even use windbg to create dump on crash, although DebugDiag is simplier to use. Point is that it is hard to guess reason without additional information, so you need to use tools to gather that information. If you can predict crash in happening in small time frame, you start from process monitor - and compare healthy machine process monitor log with failing one, if not - you may try DebugDiag, as it has capability to catch crash, especially if it is some kind of stackoverflow. If never used process monitor - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963887.aspx

Comment: OK, I'm running process monitors on both machines but it takes sometime to run into the bug (up to 24 hours) hopefully I could come back with more information

Comment: I ran process monitor and it seems that the process just spontaneously crashes even the last line in the process monitor seems to be half complete, I also did an occurrence count with a "healthy" computer and it came out surprisingly equal, any suggestions?

Comment: Do you use any unmanaged code or calls to COM or smth that is out of .NET scope?

Comment: You may try to hunt for 1st/2nd chance exceptions to find a clue with Adplus: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2012/01/27/taking-dumps-with-the-adplus-executable.aspx

Comment: I must tell all you guys that I don't think it's a code issue but rather an environment issue since I ran the code for the past 6 months over 5-6 different non-stop and it's still running, I think it is a problem with Windows 7 and/or .NET 4 framework, I found this link [2640103](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640103) in Microsoft support website and got the hotfix from Microsoft installed it but the program still fails, next step re-installing windows, any other suggestion before I do so?

Comment: OK it's not 100% proven but I think I found the solution, in all of my working machines the format in region and language section is set to English (United States) but I manually changed the short date from MM/dd/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy I forgot to do that on the failed machine once I did that it seems that the problem is fixed for now, can any one think of a reason why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out there was a hardware problem with one of the memory chips in the faulty computer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious, did the fix mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334706/fatal-execution-engine-error-79ffee24-80131506) of installing .Net 3.5 sp1 also work for you (running .net 4)??